# Strategies for parallel implementation of Lua numbers and a 64bit integer

Tags: 64-bit, lua, integer

Lua by default uses a double precision floating point (`double`) type as its only numeric type. That's nice and useful. However, I'm working on software that expects to see 64bit integers, for which I don't get around using actual 64bit integers one way or another.

The place where the integer type becomes relevant is for file sizes. Although I don't truly expect to see file sizes beyond what Lua can represent with full "integer" precision using a `double`, I want to be prepared.

What strategies can you recommend when using a 64bit integer type in parallel with the default numeric type of Lua? I don't really want to throw the default implementation overboard (and I'm not worried of its performance compared to integer arithmetics), but I need some way of representing 64bit integers up to their full precision without too much of a performance penalty.

My problem is that I'm unsure where to modify the behavior. Should I modify the syntax and extend the parser (numbers with appended LL or ULL come to mind, which to my knowledge doesn't exist in default Lua) or should I instead write my own C module and define a userdata type that represents the 64bit integer, along with library functions able to manipulate the values? ...

*Note:* yes, I am embedding Lua, so I am free to extend it whichever way I please.

Comment: Prepared for what? A double can express a file offset of over nine petabytes to the nearest byte.

Comment: @Marcelo: thank you for your comment. This will be enough for current implementations of NTFS (which is probably the main target), but will be too little for the designed file size support, which exceeds this number by far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of LuaJIT's port to ARM CPUs (which often have poor floating-point), LuaJIT implemented a "Dual-number VM", which allows it to switch between integers and floats dynamically as needed. You could use this yourself, just switch between 64-bit integers and doubles instead of 32-bit integers and floats.

It's currently live in builds, so you may want to consider using LuaJIT as your Lua "interpreter." Or you could use it as a way to learn how to do this sort of thing.

However, I do agree with Marcelo; the 53-bit mantissa should be plenty. You shouldn't really *need* this for a good 10 years or so.

Comment: Thank you. It's kind of a double-edged sword though, relying on something that is not really true (i.e. the assumption that I can have full 64bit precision when I don't). But In this respect I really needed someone's opinion. My users are simply not qualified to comment on this, so thank you. Thanks also for the comment concerning LuaJIT. Reading about it on the mailing list from all the announcements about releases and betas.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest storing your data outside of Lua and use some type of reference to retrieve it when calling your other libraries.  You can then push various results onto the Lua stack for the user the see, you can even retrieve the value as a string to be precise, but I would avoid modifying them in Lua and relying on the Lua values when calling your external library.

Comment: That's not too bad an idea. Also, I could raise an assertion or something more visible in a release build when that happens. For the most part this is meant to be informative.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to need floating-point precision at any point in the program, you can just redefine `LUA_NUMBER` to `__int64` (or whatever 64-bit int may be in your environment) in [luaconf.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/luaconf.h.html).

Otherwise, you can just bring in another library to handle your integers- for *infinite* precision, you can use a bignum library such as [lhf's lbn](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbn).